# C++ Builder XE unresolved external error

Tags: c++, linker, c++builder, c++builder-xe

I have the following header file containing a class and some variables

```
extern bool akwizycja_w_toku;
extern LPCTSTR pFileName;
extern int numer_akwizycji;

class Akwizycja : public TThread
{
public:
    __fastcall Akwizycja(bool CreateSuspended);
    void __fastcall Akwizycja::UpdateLabels();
    Akwizycja::Akwizycja() {}
};
```

(just a sample, there is more but it doesn't matter)
furthermore I've got the main project

```
#include "Akwizycja.h"
void __fastcall Akwizycja::UpdateLabels()
{
    Form1->Label12->Caption=FloatToStrF(dRate,ffFixed,8,4);
    Form1->Label13->Caption=FloatToStrF(ActualRate,ffFixed,8,3);
    Form1->Label14->Caption=FloatToStrF(EffectiveRate,ffFixed,8,3);
    Form1->Label15->Caption=pow(2,Clock_Divider);
}
```

where arguments like dRate or ffFixed are some of the extern variables.
The problem starts when I want to use some of the functions

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Akwizycja* new_object = new Akwizycja;
}
```

I get [ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_dRate' referenced from D:\DF\DEBUG\WIN32\RECEIVER.OBJ
for all of the variables used.

Suppose it's some path-setting issue, but all of them are added. Many thanks for any piece of advice.

Comment: Because `dRate`  or `ffFixed` are not defined in any source file?

Comment: Have you defined `dRate`? None of the code you've posted defines it.